# update the Textview showing the user-entered text, Intent.getStringExtra()

Tags: android-intent

My variables are declared below:

```
 static private final int GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
        static private final String URL = "http://www.google.com";
        static private final String TAG = "Lab-Intents";


        static private final String CHOOSER_TEXT = "Load " + URL + " with:";


        private TextView mUserTextView;
```

I'm not sure how to complete code in onActivityResult() method. I'm not sure if I updated the Textview showing the user-entered text correctly. I have to use Intent.getStringExtra(). which I used but as getIntent().getStringExtra("mUserTextView");

```
private void startImplicitActivation() {

        Log.i(TAG, "Entered startImplicitActivation()");



                 Uri url = Uri.parse(URL);            
                 Intent baseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url);
             Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(baseIntent, CHOOSER_TEXT);
             Log.i(TAG,"Chooser Intent Action:" + chooserIntent.getAction());

             startActivity(chooserIntent);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Entered onActivityResult()");

    // TODO - Process the result only if this method received both a
    // RESULT_OK result code and a recognized request code
    // If so, update the Textview showing the user-entered text.

if (requestCode == GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE){
    if (requestCode == RESULT_OK){
    getIntent().getStringExtra("mUserTextView");    
    }
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To update the label, you should use:

```
if ( resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE ) {
    mUserTextView.setText( data.getStringExtra("resultado"));
}
```

Remember to call "ExplicitlyLoadedActivity", with the request code GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivityLoaderActivity.this, ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.class); 
startActivityForResult( myIntent, GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE ); // just to be sure about Request code
```

Change the word "resultado", for the one you used in enterClicked() for ExplicitlyLoadedActivity

```
String givenText = mEditText.getText().toString(); // Getting the user input
Intent intencion = new Intent(); // Getting ready to comeback
intencion.putExtra("resultado", givenText); // I use "resultado", spanish guy
setResult(RESULT_OK, intencion); // RESULT_OK is a constant = 1 
finish();
```

Good luck width the lab in coursera, also I'm doing it. Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much, but startActivityForResult( intent, GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE ); gives me an error. It is ok when I write it like this   startActivityForResult( getIntent(), GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE );

Comment: I edited the answer, check if it works for you. In the intent, be sure you are using the Activities names

Answer (score 0):

The static method `createChooser(Intent, CharSequence)` from the type Intent should be accessed in a static way. This is shown when I'm running the same code at `chooserIntent.createChooser(map,CHOOSER_TEXT);`

//CODE

```
private void startImplicitActivation() 
{
    Log.i(TAG, "Entered startImplicitActivation()");

    // TODO - Create a base intent for viewing a URL 
    // (HINT:  second parameter uses parse() from the Uri class)
    Intent map = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(URL));


    // TODO - Create a chooser intent, for choosing which Activity
    // will carry out the baseIntent. Store the Intent in the 
    // chooserIntent variable below. HINT: using the Intent class' 
    // createChooser())


    Intent chooserIntent=null;
    chooserIntent.createChooser(map,CHOOSER_TEXT);

    Log.i(TAG,"Chooser Intent Action:" + chooserIntent.getAction());
    // TODO - Start the chooser Activity, using the chooser intent
    startActivity(chooserIntent);

}
```

This causes an error when I'm running the app as:

```
unfortunately the project has stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

chooserIntent is null. First create it :
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(map, CHOOSER_TEXT);